# Sender address rejected: Domain example.com does not accept mail (nullMX)

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, mailer

I'm trying to add multiple mail driver

I have two emails in same Host Server
One for financial messages
The second is for regular messages

.env file

```
MAIL_MAILER_1=smtp
MAIL_HOST_1=mail.privateemail.com
MAIL_PORT_1=465
MAIL_USERNAME_1=payments@example.com
MAIL_PASSWORD_1=example(Lw8S
MAIL_ENCRYPTION_1=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS_1=payments@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME_1="${APP_NAME}"


MAIL_MAILER_2=smtp
MAIL_HOST_2=mail.privateemail.com
MAIL_PORT_2=465
MAIL_USERNAME_2=no-reply@example.com
MAIL_PASSWORD_2=example$7Sweffake
MAIL_ENCRYPTION_2=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS_2=no-reply@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME_2="${APP_NAME}"
```

mail.php file

```
        'mail_payments' => [

            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST_1', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT_1', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION_1', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME_1'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD_1'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN'),

        ],
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST_2', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT_2', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION_2', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME_2'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD_2'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN'),
        ],
```

Mail_Paid_Profits_Controller.php file

```
public function send_form(Request $request){

$name            = $request->input('name');
$email           = $request->input('email');
$amount          = $request->input('amount');
$note            = $request->input('note');
$image           = $request->file('image');
$date_now        = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');


$mailData = [
    'title' => "Hello $name ,  we have sent you your earnings",
    'body'  =>  "On $date_now, we paid you $$amount  as a payment from your monthly earnings.",
    'note'  =>  $note,
    'image' =>  $image

];


Mail::mailer('mail_payments')->to($email)->send(new Paid_Profits($mailData));



Session::flash('message', "Sent successfully");

return redirect()->back();



    }
```

One for financial messages
The second is for regular messages

When I add the MAIL_MAILER_1 data in the MAIL_MAILER_2, it works successfully,
which means that the .env file data is correct

I mean, when I add the financial messages  data in the regular messages becasue it default  SMTP , it works, but when I add it in a new data in the MAIL_MAILER_1 and use it , it does not work

I searched a lot and did not know the problem
Knowing that it is not a fault DNS as I said it works Via default SMTP
But when I add it as a second MAIL_MAILER_1 it doesn't work and I get this error:
and run :

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Expected response code "250/251/252" but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.27 hello@example.com: Sender address rejected: Domain example.com does not accept mail (nullMX)".

error line :

Mail::mailer('mail_payments')->to($email)->send(new Paid_Profits($mailData));

[image]

I suspect that there is an error in the mail.php or Mail_Paid_Profits_Controller file